# How to trim whitespaces from inside of string with min_length and max_length validation?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to trim whitespace from inside of string with min_length and max_length validation?

```
name = serializers.CharField(min_length=18, max_length=18, trim_whitespace=True, allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, required=False)
```

`test_string_that_should_be_invalid = "1111111111111111 1"`

`test_string_valid = "111111111111111111"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trim whitespace keyword argument doesn't run any extra validators. All it does is trim the whitespace at the end of a string using `.strip()` when saving the value to the database.

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    # We're lenient with allowing basic numerics to be coerced into strings,
    # but other types should fail. Eg. unclear if booleans should represent as `true` or `True`,
    # and composites such as lists are likely user error.
    if isinstance(data, bool) or not isinstance(data, (str, int, float,)):
        self.fail('invalid')
    value = str(data)
    return value.strip() if self.trim_whitespace else value
```

It sounds like you want to make sure that there are no spaces anywhere in the string. To do so you would need to write a [custom field-level validator](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation). Something like:

```
if ' ' in value:
    raise serializers.ValidationError('Value cannot contain spaces')
```

Comment: trim_whitespace is not working in my case. I want to trim whitespace from input before adding to DB. Can you please assist me?